# Android:Datepicker dialog causes a crash when put inside a tab

Tags: android, tabs, datepicker

I have successfully made a datepicker dialog and have added in in one of my tabs. But what I am trying to achieve is a tab within a tab and the contents of that tab is my date picker. The issue is that it crashes.

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is like this

tab1_

```
    |
 tab2 (found inside tab1)_
                          |
                          Datepicker
```

logcat report

```
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@53238480 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at com.example.androidtablayout.$1.onClick(Act.java:111)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-03 18:49:47.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1651):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 18:49:47.071: W/ActivityManager(475):   Force finishing activity com.example.androidtablayout/.AndroidTabLayoutActivity
```

codesnippet for datepicker

```
inputDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view)


            {
                int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(Act.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                            c.set(year, month, day);
                            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(c.getTime());
                            inputStart.setText(date);

                            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                             }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);


                    dpd.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: It looks like the datepicker is trying to get added to the wrong activity. Could you please post some code? Like the part where you're calling the dialogfragment.

Comment: Done. Thank you. Could you please elaborate on what you said about the wrong activity? in which part should I check that?

Comment: What is *VacLeave.class*? an activity?

Comment: I pasted the wrong code sorry. The name of the class is act

Comment: So please edit again and paste relevant code?

Comment: Okey, *act.class* extend from Activity?